# Issue with natively binding my .Net core app to single .exe

Tags: dnu, asp.net5

I've created a sample app to get an idea on .Net Core with `Web -> ConsoleApp(Package)`. I've resolved all the dependency issues but when I try to compile natively with

```
dotnet-compile --native
```

it's returning this error:

```
dotnet compile --native
Compiling DemoApp for DNXCore,Version=v5.0

Compilation succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time elapsed 00:00:09.2220793
Input Assembly: ..\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DemoApp\
src\DemoApp\bin\Debug\dnxcore50\DemoApp.dll
libcpmt.lib(nothrow.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': valu
e '1700' doesn't match value '1900' in Runtime.lib(RuntimeInstance.obj)
libcpmt.lib(newaop.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value
 '1700' doesn't match value '1900' in Runtime.lib(RuntimeInstance.obj)
Runtime.lib(objecthandle.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void
__cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned __int64)" (??3@YAXPEAX_K@Z)
Runtime.lib(stressLog.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __c
decl operator delete(void *,unsigned __int64)" (??3@YAXPEAX_K@Z)
Runtime.lib(gcwks.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
 operator delete(void *,unsigned __int64)" (??3@YAXPEAX_K@Z)
Runtime.lib(handletablescan.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "vo
id __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned __int64)" (??3@YAXPEAX_K@Z)
Runtime.lib(module.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdec
l operator delete(void *,unsigned __int64)" (??3@YAXPEAX_K@Z)
Runtime.lib(allocheap.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __c
decl operator delete(void *,unsigned __int64)" (??3@YAXPEAX_K@Z)
Runtime.lib(gceewks.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cde
cl operator delete(void *,unsigned __int64)" (??3@YAXPEAX_K@Z)
Runtime.lib(RestrictedCallouts.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
"void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned __int64)" (??3@YAXPEAX_K@Z)
Runtime.lib(RuntimeInstance.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "vo
id __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned __int64)" (??3@YAXPEAX_K@Z)
Runtime.lib(CachedInterfaceDispatch.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external sy
mbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned __int64)" (??3@YAXPEAX_K@Z)
Runtime.lib(threadstore.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void _
_cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned __int64)" (??3@YAXPEAX_K@Z)
Runtime.lib(PalRedhawkMinWin.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "v
oid __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned __int64)" (??3@YAXPEAX_K@Z)
Runtime.lib(handletablecore.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __s
td_terminate
Runtime.lib(handletablecache.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __
std_terminate
Runtime.lib(handletablescan.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __s
td_terminate
Runtime.lib(RestrictedCallouts.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
__std_terminate
Runtime.lib(objecthandle.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_
terminate
Runtime.lib(stressLog.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_ter
minate
Runtime.lib(handletable.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_t
erminate
Runtime.lib(RuntimeInstance.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __s
td_terminate
Runtime.lib(CachedInterfaceDispatch.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external sy
mbol __std_terminate
Runtime.lib(startup.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_termi
nate
Runtime.lib(allocheap.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_ter
minate
Runtime.lib(gcwks.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __acrt_iob_fu
nc referenced in function printf
bootstrapper.lib(main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __acrt_io
b_func
Runtime.lib(gcwks.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_commo
n_vfprintf referenced in function printf
bootstrapper.lib(main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_c
ommon_vfprintf
bootstrapper.lib(main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Init_thr
ead_header referenced in function GetModuleSection
bootstrapper.lib(main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Init_thr
ead_footer referenced in function GetModuleSection
bootstrapper.lib(main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __managed
__Main referenced in function main
bootstrapper.lib(main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Init_thr
ead_epoch
..\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DemoApp\src\DemoApp\bin\
Debug\dnxcore50\native\DemoApp.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals

Linking of intermediate files failed.
```

The expected is to get exe file. Even normal **dotnet publish** isn't working fully as I'm only getting dll, pdb files. Exe is not getting published.

[No .exe file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMnp7.png)

Can I convert this app to single .exe file ?I'm trying using x64 native command prompt to run the command.

Please suggest.

**Edit**: Tried installing the new installer but no luck. 
But **dnu publish** is working fine.

[dnu publish result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8PZf.png)

**I want the output as exe and dlls or native exe only but sadly fails.**

Comment: Well, that's a very basic failure to get the job done.  Maybe you got the beta bits mixed up.  But frankly CoreRT is entirely too early to try yet, last update was 2 hours ago and lots of changes last week.  You'll need to give them time to complete the project.

Comment: @HansPassant - I was just wondering if it's the C++ runtime issues. I've tried updating with the latest [setup](http://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/) but issue persists. In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34580599/building-a-net-core-app-via-command-line-so-that-it-works-on-a-machine-without), he's able to natively compile

Comment: As noted, what happened in January is not predictor for what happens today.  This project is changing fast and you *will* have trouble.  Use the proper channel to provide feedback if you want to help with this project, that is not SO, click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/issues).  Or just wait a month and try again.

Comment: Changed the tags, as this discussion was about RC1. Users should now upgrade to RC2, http://dot.net