# Build ASP.NET Core on Windows Server (without Visual studio) for CI/CD

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore, dotnet-cli, dotnet-restore

*This is not duplicate of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38773590/can-i-build-net-core-applications-on-a-windows-server-without-visual-studio-ins), although goal is the same, but the error is not.*

I want to build my ASP.NET Core on machine without Visual Studio installed.

*I need this, because I am setting GitLab CI/CD.*

Just for test purpose I open console I execute `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` in folder where `.sln` file is. I get the following error in both cases:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\NuGet.targets(103,5): error : The
>   local source 'C:\Users\matjaz.cof\.dotnet\NuGetFallbackFolder' doesn't
>   exist.

Full log:

```
C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\7cab42e4\0\web\app>dotnet restore
  Restoring packages for C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\7cab42e4\0\web\app\App.Web.Core\App.Web.Core.csproj...
  Restoring packages for C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\7cab42e4\0\web\app\App.Web.Library.Tests\App.Web.Library.Tests.csproj...
  Restoring packages for C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\7cab42e4\0\web\app\App.Web.Core.Tests\App.Web.Core.Tests.csproj...
  Restoring packages for C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\7cab42e4\0\web\app\App.Web.Library\App.Web.Library.csproj...
  Restoring packages for C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\7cab42e4\0\web\app\App.Web.Hosting\App.Web.Hosting.csproj...
  Restore completed in 93,72 ms for C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\7cab42e4\0\web\app\App.Web.Hosting\App.Web.Hosting.csproj.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\NuGet.targets(103,5): error : The local source 'C:\Users\matjaz.cof\.dotnet\NuGetFallbackFolder' doesn't exist. [C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\7cab42e4\0\web\app\App.Web.sln]
```

Answer in provided thread says that all I need is Dotnet SDK, which I installed:

```
C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\7cab42e4\0\web\app>dotnet --version
2.1.4
```

Folder really doesn't exists on Windows server, but it exists on my development machine (with VS 2017 installed).
I search entire `c:` on Windows Server for folder `NuGetFallbackFolder` and found it in `c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder`.

Why `dotnet restore/build` search for folder under username and what do I need to change?

**Edited:** (@MartinUllrich)

This is the content of `c:\Users\matjaz.cof\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply solved it by coping `c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\` to `c:\Users\matjaz.cof\.dotnet\NuGetFallbackFolder\`.

I couldn't think of anything else. Maybe uninstalling old .NET Core runtimes and SDKs would also do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

This fallback folder path was used during the 2.0 preview timeframe of .NET Core.

You can delete package sources referencing this directory from the `C:\Users\ matjaz.cof\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config` file.

Comment: I deleted complete folder `C:\Users\ matjaz.cof\AppData\Roaming\NuGet` there was only `NuGet.Config` file inside, but the error stays and it is the same. I also close and open cmd and powershell (just in case if something is cached).

Comment: is a nuget.config file recreated? does it contain a reference to that directory? I'd suggest just editing the nuget.config to remove the directory

Comment: Yes, folder is recreated and no, there is no reference to `NuGetFallbackFolder`. I edited my question with content of `NuGet.Config` file.

Comment: I event restart the server, but I still get the error. Any other idea?